# "Cannot use a scalar value as an array" for undefined values

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code:

```
function Biz_GetAccountsPerMarket($site = "", $cache = true){
    if($site == ""){
        $site = $_SESSION["sitedirect_current_site"];
    }

    $aAccounts = Sys_OptionsGet("sys_site/".$site, "account", $cache);

    $aAccountInfo   = array();
    $aVatAccount    = Biz_GetVatAccounts($site, $cache);
    $aSalesAccount  = Biz_GetSalesAccounts($site, $cache);

    foreach((array)$aAccounts as $code => $data){
        foreach((array)$data["data"] as $market => $aItem){
            $aAccountInfo[$market][$code] = $aItem;
            $aAccountInfo[$market][$code]["vat"]           = $aVatAccount[$aItem["vat_account_code"]]["value"];
            $aAccountInfo[$market][$code]["vat_account"]   = $aVatAccount[$aItem["vat_account_code"]]["account"];
            $aAccountInfo[$market][$code]["sales_account"] = $aSalesAccount[$aItem["sales_account_code"]]["account"];
        }
    }

    return $aAccountInfo;
}
```

The four innermost lines in the nested loop generates warnings: "Cannot use a scalar value as an array".

Adding lines that initialises `$aAccountInfo[$market]` and `$aAccountInfo[$market][$code]` to empty arrays first silences the errors, but this is far from the only place in our code where nested arrays are initialised in this way; and I can't figure out *why* it is a problem in the first place.

The following code *should* reproduce the problem; as far as I can tell; but doesn't:

```
<?php    
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$aTest = [];

$aTest['key']['key'] = 'sausage';
```

If `$aItem` was a string or false, or any scalar; I could understand what the problem is; but then the warning should only happen for the last three lines, not all four.

There are other weird things happening there, I hope they're all connected. This is the only one I've managed to isolate enough to ask a question about.

Is it possble to set the default value created by array access somehow?

edit:

I've noticed that many strings that are generates have an extraneous "0". This breaks things, like SQL. If empty array values somehow default to "0" or something, that would explain a lot. I have no idea how that could happen though. I'm currently grepping for "register_tick_function"...

Comment: What happens if you `print_r($aItem);` in your loop? Are there any "blank" or "null" `$aItem`s?

Comment: Unfortunately it is on a production system and I haven't yet figured out a way to reproduce it harmlessly, and haven't been able to debug the _actual_ value. Running Sys_OptionsGet(...) that generates $aAccounts tells me no, they're all arrays, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if arrays have the expected keys. Something like this:

```
$aAccountInfo[$market][$code]["vat"] = isset($aItem["vat_account_code"]) ? (isset($aVatAccount[$aItem["vat_account_code"]]) ? $aVatAccount[$aItem["vat_account_code"]]["value"] : []) : [];
```

Comment: No, that is a Notice: Undefined index. Or Warning: Illegal string offset if $aItem is a string. Curiously, if $aItem is 1, there is no warning, notice or anything. Just null.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid your code is wrong

This line

```
$aAccountInfo[$market][$code] = $aItem;
```

creates the new occurance containing a SCALAR value and you then try and add a sub array onto that scalar value, hence the error

If you do this instead

```
$t = array();
$t['item']          = $aItem;
$t["vat"]           = $aVatAccount[$aItem["vat_account_code"]]["value"];
$t["vat_account"]   = $aVatAccount[$aItem["vat_account_code"]]["account"];
$t["sales_account"] = $aSalesAccount[$aItem["sales_account_code"]]["account"];

$aAccountInfo[$market][$code] = $t;
```

Then you will get a sub array created with all the values in it;

Comment: $aItem isn't scalar and even if it was, that would not explain why the first line _also_ warns. And if it _was_ the problem, why doesn't the minimal example report an error?

Comment: Add another line to your minimal example `$aTest['key']['key']['and'] = 'chips';` Then it will generate an error

Comment: But then the minimal code doesn't reflect the actual code. Or at least, I cannot see how. I know that the warning triggers when there _actually_ is a scalar in place; but as far as I can tell there is no way for there to _be_ a scalar there in the first place.

Comment: I believe it is saying the `$aAccountInfo[$market][$code] = $aItem;` has set a scalar and therefore this and subsequent lines is the issue `$aAccountInfo[$market][$code]["vat"] = $aVatAccount[$aItem["vat_account_code"]]["value"];`

Comment: Then it would complain about the three lines where there is  a problem, not raise a problem on the first assignment. I have some more symptoms and will update the question.

Comment: A "pure" example from another place: `$aTypes = array (); $aTypes["ordr"]["icon"] = "biz_order_50/images/icon_order.gif";`; first two lines in a function...  'Error: ' => 'Cannot use a scalar value as an array',